# Importing and naming a declaration file in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I've written an NPM package using TypeScript and I noticed that about 30% of the code written in the file is interfaces, type aliases and other TypeScript stuff.

So I thought maybe I can create a declaration file, a `.d.ts` file, and I can put everything related to TypeScript inside this file.

Now this is how the working directory looks:

```
src/
├── index.ts
└── stack-player.ts
```

This is `index.ts`:

```
export { default } from './stack-player'
```

and this is `stack-player.ts`:

```
type Stack = string // let's make it simple

export default function stackPlayer(stack: Stack){
  // ... a bunch of code
}
```

I've created the `.d.ts` file as follows:

```
src/
├── index.ts
├── stack-player.ts
└── stack-player.d.ts
```

and I moved the type definitions to the `stack-player.d.ts` file and exported them as follows:

```
// this is stack-player.d.ts file
export type Stack = string // let's make it simple
```

Now, I imported the `stack-player.d.ts` file into the `stack-player.ts` file:

```
import { type Stack } from './stack-player.d.ts'

export default function stackPlayer(stack: Stack){
  // ... a bunch of code
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> An import path cannot end with a '.d.ts' extension. Consider importing
> './stack-player' instead

[image]

Following the error message, I removed the file extension, but this results in wrong file, because now it imports itself:

[image]

I have a couple of questions:

1. How to name these declaration files? How many declaration files do we make per project? for example, now I only have `stack-player.ts` file, but later I might have another file called `mergeObjects.ts` file, so I don't want to put all the types of them in one declaration file, I want to have multiple declaration files, each one matching a `.ts` file.
2. I saw many people use the name `index.d.ts`, what's special about this name? How to import it? I can't use this name, because I currently have a file named `index.ts` so naming the file `index.d.ts` will prevent me from importing it, the same way this problem occurred in the above example.
3. If I downloaded a package which is written in JavaScript, and is not written in TypeScript, and it has no `@types/package-name` declaration that I can install from NPM, and I wanted to create a declaration file for it myself, What should I call the `.d.ts` file? what name should I choose? How to make TypeScript understand that this file is for that package? Where should I import it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaration files are used to type existing javascript files. In your case you most likely want to keep your types and interfaces in a a separate ts/tsx file.

I strongly suggest to familiarising with [typescript's documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) on declaration files.

Now that the questions can be more aligned with how declarations are used we can paraphrase the questions to answer them in a way that is more aligned with how TypeScript is used in the industry.

1. How to name typescript files that only contain types?

You most likely want to have an easy to understand domain names. For example if you have a file that contains user related types, you can name it `userTypes.ts`

2. What is special about `index.d.ts` filename?

In nodejs module resolution works in a way that you can require a module by a directory name if a javascript file inside of it is called `index.js`. So `require('./foo')` would actually require `./foo/index.js`. Back to declaration files. As they are used to type existing files. It is likely that the files that you saw were located next to `index.js` files.

Comment: Why call the file `userTypes.ts`, why not `userTypes.d.ts` ?

Comment: because `*.d.ts` is used to declare types for existing files. Generally it is possible. But these files do not get transpired to js when tsc runs. So everyone working in the project would have to keep this in mind. If someone forgets it and places an `enum` in a d.ts file these won't be available at runtime and will cause an error.